# Render Views and Partial Views depending on ModelState

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

I'm using an Ajax request to render a partial view, but when the model has some errors it should render a full View, what's wrong with my code, or what should change

```
    [Authorize(Roles = AuthStrings.AdminRole)]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(Module module)
    {
        try
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                new ModuleService().Insert(module);
                return PartialView("_ModuleResult", module.DataUrl);
            }
            return View(module);
        }
        catch (ModelExistsException e)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("Name", e.Message);
            return Redirect
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
    }
```

I'm using Ajax Helpers

```
    @using (Ajax.BeginForm("Create", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "Post",    UpdateTargetId = "folderPath"}))
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        <div class="form-horizontal">
              ..Here is form fields
        </div>
    }
    <div id="folderPath">
    </div>
    <div>
        @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
    </div>
```

Comment: You need to show the ajax code

Comment: Your Ajax part should handle that - show it as @StephenMuecke suggested.

Comment: Maybe there is a way to render a full view directly from controller